# Xcode - Setting Other C Flags on dependent projects

Tags: iphone, xcode, gcc

I have an Xcode project (for an iPhone application) that uses cocos2d. I have cocos2d set up as a dependent project, so it builds alongside my project.

Now I need to set a compiler flag to Cocos, and I can't find where to do it.

I tried setting the compiler flag in my build settings, but it doesn't propagate to the dependent projects. I checked the different Get Info panels, but I cannot find where to do it.

It seems to me that this should be possible, since the dependent projects come from svn:externals and it makes no sense to have to change the build settings in these projects.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to have your project settings automatically propagate to a dependent project (you probably wouldn't want that usually anyways).

You have to set it in the dependent project (either for the entire project or a specific target).

I.e., double click the dependent project to open it then change the compiler flags as you would in any project.

Comment: I was able to do this, but I was looking for a way to set the flags on the project that includes the dependency, so the dependent project is left unmodified.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that is possible.